# How correct list-style displayed in firefox?

Tags: list

although the list-style for content is set to 'disk' in child-themes style.css,
it is displayed as 'decimal'. In chrome-browser it is OK.

Is there any workaround to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `"disk"` with `"disc"`

Here is some background: It has been reported, and they don't want to fix it:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1027647

based on a misinterpretation of:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-counter-styles-3/#extending-css2

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870383/css-list-style-type-disk-showing-numbers)

Comment: Thank you! I modified the code in the style.css to "disc". Nothing happened at first, I cleared all cache, no change. But after I added the code also to custom-css it is working fine. Have you an explanation for that? That the code-inserting in style.css has no effect?

Comment: your custom-css overwrite the previous style, you should check which stylesheet your theme is currently loading, may b your theme has skins options and each skin has different stylesheets, its depends on your theme :)

Comment: yes, I thought that. There is one style.css in the parent genesis-theme, and one in the lifestyle-pro child-theme. In both files I had changed it from 'disk' to 'disc'.  It is the third issue with needing custom-css because the style.css - editing was  not enough.
It could be that it has to do with a laborious cache-clearing on my site because of CDN- and host-server- and browser-cache are involved in it. I often have to purge cache on 5 different places. So I will wait if it will work without custom-css in this case. I deleted it and observe it.